# How can I login into my php website using freelancer account?

Tags: php, api

I have an php website with login form and I want every visitors can able to login into my website using their freelancer account....

Is there any one who can assist me on this or send some examples for the same?

Comment: What have you tried?  Or are you hoping that we will all do freelance work for free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard approach for this type of system is [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). The site you want to use for authentication will need to support it or provide some equivalent. You can't use arbitrary third party login credentials.

(Well, you *could* use arbitrary credentials, but that would require you to access usernames and passwords for third party sites (violating their T&Cs in most cases) and then login to them yourself to see if they were correct. Technically possible, practically and legally insane).